# Creating a table with a fixed number of rows

Tags: javascript, html-table

Using Javascript, Html and BFO (Big Faceless Org) PDF Generator, I need to create a table with fixed number of rows for every page in a sales order. Basically, the table should consist of fixed 10 rows, however rows populated with information may only be 1 or 2 rows. The other rows will be empty.

Anyone can help?

Currently all I have is:

```
for(I=0;i<=salesitem.length;i++){
    document.write('<tr><td>salesitem[I]</td></tr>');
}
```

That generates one td row for every sales item. However, I want a fixed 10 rows in the table.

Comment: It's obviously not easy to demonstrate that you've already tried something when it comes to PDF, especially when I have no idea if "BFO" is a graphical design tool or you're calling actual code... but SO is not a code writing service, and this sounds like a request for code

Comment: BFO is actually a PDF generator. Basically we code in HTML and it generates the PDF for us

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with the tiny piece of code you've supplied...

- javascript is case sensitive, therefore `I` and `i` are different variables
- looping from 0 to i<=salesitems.length will end in an error, because if length is 10 and you use salesitem[10] it will fail (arrays are 0-based, and therefore an array with length of 10 has items 0 to 9)
- I believe you think that `salesitem[I]` will process like PHP, it won't.  PHP allows you to use `echo "print this $varName"`, javascript simply doesn't allow that.

Try something along these lines...

```
for (i = 0; i < salesitem.length; i++) {
  document.write('<tr><td>' + salesitem[i] + '</td></tr>');
}
for (i = salesitem.length; i < 10; i++) {
  document.write('<tr><td></td></tr>');
}
```

The first loop will display everything in your array (including any entries over 10)

The second loop will display lines to complete the table (if there are less than 10 entries)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
for (var i=0;i<10;i++) { 
    document.write("<tr>");

    //This will depend entirely upon what conditions have to be met
    //in order for you to display the content of each row
    if(variable == 'condition') {
         document.write("<td>content</td>");
    }

    document.write("</tr>");
}
```

Comment: I can loop the rows. However, I need something which can help me populate the items in the sales order for every line.